Additive characters over a Number Field
Given any non-zero
integral ideal $\mathfrak{b}$ of $K$, an additive character modulo $\mathfrak{b}$
is defined to be a non-zero function $\sigma$ on $\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{b}$ which satisfies
$$
\sigma(\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2})=
\sigma(\alpha_{1})
\sigma(\alpha_{2}),
$$
for any $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}\in \mathfrak{o}$. It satisfies the basic orthogonality relation
$$\sum_{\sigma \bmod{\mathfrak{b}}} \sigma(\alpha) = 
\begin{cases}
 N(\mathfrak{b}), & \mbox{if $\mathfrak{b}\mid (\alpha)$,}\\
0, & \mbox{otherwise,}
\end{cases}$$
for any non-zero $\alpha\in \mathfrak{b}$,
where the notation
$\sum_{\sigma \bmod{\mathfrak{b}}}$ means that the sum is taken over
additive characters modulo $\mathfrak{b}$.
I am not sure how to prove this. I just saw this definition and have trouble proving this relation.
What I tried is,
If $\mathfrak{b}| (\alpha)$, then $\alpha \in (\alpha)=\mathfrak{b}\mathfrak{c}$, hence $\alpha=\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i b_i$ and thus $\sigma(\alpha)=\sigma(\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i b_i)=\sigma(0)=1$ as we are reducing modulo $\mathfrak{b}$ and we sum this over $N(\mathfrak{b})$ distinct dirichlet characters and this proves the first case. Is this correct?
And how can I prove the second case?

If alpha does not belong to b, it represents a non-trivial element of the quotient, hence, by a non-trivial but standard fact about finite abelian groups, there is a character sigma_o, not vanishing on that element. Now multiply the sum, whose non-vanishing you want to show, by sigma_0(alpha).

Okay, Any reference for this theory?

See https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/charthy.pdf to get a general background on characters of finite abelian groups. Do you know that $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak b$ has size ${\rm N}(\mathfrak b)$?

As pointed out in the comment, if you peel the cover, this is a standard result in representation theory.
Since $K$ is a number field, $\mathfrak o / \mathfrak b$ is a finite abelian group. So this boils down to show $$\sum_{\sigma: G\rightarrow\mathbb C^{\times}} \sigma(g) = \begin{cases} |G| & \text{ if } g=1 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$
where $\sigma:G\rightarrow\mathbb C^{\times}$ is any group homomorphism.
While this is standard, I'll give a self-contained proof. More generally, you can refer to any book on representation theory, e.g. Section 3.5 of Etingof etc, or Chapter 18 of S. Lang.
If $g=1$, then $\sigma(g)=1$ for all $\sigma$, so this is trivial. Otherwise, the key idea is essentially to treat all the characters as a group. I'll just add more details to @m.s 's answer. That is show that if $\sigma, \tau$ are both characters, then $(\sigma\tau)(g):=\sigma(g)\tau(g)$ is also a character. Under this, it's easy to show all characters form a group, hence  the map $\sigma\mapsto \sigma\tau$ is a permutation of all characters for any $\tau$.
Therefore $$\sum_{\sigma} \sigma(g) = \sum_{\sigma}(\sigma\tau)(g)=\tau(g)\sum_{\sigma} \sigma(g)$$ $$(\tau(g)-1)\sum_{\sigma}\sigma(g)=0$$ To show $\sum_{\sigma}\sigma(g)=0$, it suffices to show there exists at least one $\tau$ such that $\tau(g)\not=1$. There are different ways to finish. One way is to cite the structure theorem of finite (generated) abelian groups so $G\simeq\prod_i(\mathbb Z/n_i\mathbb Z)$, and if $g=(a_1, \cdots, a_n)\in G$, where $a_i\not=0$, we can do the projection $G\rightarrow \mathbb Z/n_i\mathbb Z$, and easily find a character $\chi$ of the cyclic group $\mathbb Z/n_i\mathbb Z$ such that $\chi(a_i)$ a primitive $m$-th root of unity where $m$ is the order of $a_i$ .

This is probably best understood abstractly, by Pontryagin duality for finite abelain groups. Let $A$ be a such a finite abelian group. (You can apply the discussion to $A = \mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{b}$.)
The dual group $\widehat{A}$ is, by definition, the group of all homomorphisms $\sigma: A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, with point-wise multiplication. What we need to show is that for $a \in A \setminus \{1\}$, there is $\sigma \in \hat{A}$ such that $\sigma(a) \neq 1$ (then apply the hint in my comment). To do that, we can use that $A$ is isomorphic to a product of cyclic groups (by the structure theorem for finite abelian groups). Fix one isomorphism, and consider the image of $a$ under it. It will be non-trivial in one of the cyclic groups, say $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, constituting the factors of the product. Using exponentials, you can construct a character of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, not vanishing on the image of $a$ and then transfer it back to $A$ via the isomorphism.
